# Conditionally import a module on C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Is there a way to conditionally import a module on `C++20` without a preprocessor directive?

pseudo-code:

```
if WINDOWS:
    import my_module;
else:
    import other_module;
```

If there's no way, what would be the cleanest way of do it with the preprocessor?

Comment: I have not tried, but maybe it works with `if constexpr`?

Comment: Can you write a compilant example?

Comment: Well no, since `import` must be declared in global scope, and `if constexpr` can only be used inside a function.

Comment: @prapin: I don't know why you would want to avoid the preprocessor here. The only reason to import a module is because you're writing code that uses it. If so, then any code that conditionally uses the conditionally imported module would have to use the same condition. And the only tool C++ has for *static* conditional code is preprocessor directives.

Comment: No. This should be a compile-time option. Use the preprocessor.

Comment: C++20 module is a compilation module, not runtime loadable module so obviously you must use a compile-time option, i.e. preprocessor

Comment: But also the C compiler can make decisions, even if it is a deterministic one. Especially with `constexpr` computations. The question is, if this can be used for module loading. Perhaps loading both modules and using `using` and namespaces is an option?

Comment: No, there's not an option, because the implementation details of any of the two different modules are OS sensitives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to have multiple implementations of the same functionality (for example, platform dependent) then cleaner way of doing this is to have multiple implementation units for the common module interface.

For example, we want to have "my_module" module that provides platform dependent functionality `void show_notification(std::string)`.

We can have one common module interface file "my_module.ixx" that contains declarations:

```
// my_module.ixx

export module my_module;

import <string>;

export void show_notification(std::string text);
```

Then we can have multiple module implementation units, one for each of the platforms:

```
// my_module_windows.cpp

module;
// Windows specific includes
module my_module;

// Windows specific includes

void show_notification(std::string text) {
 // Windows specific code ...
}
```

```
// my_module_linux.cpp

module;
// Linux specific includes
module my_module;

// Linux specific includes

void show_notification(std::string text) {
 // Linux specific code ...
}
```

Both `my_module_linux.cpp` and `my_module_windows.cpp` provides implementation for `my_module`.

Then we can use build system to include suitable module implementation unit in our build depending on platform or other settings.

For example if we include `my_module_windows.cpp` in the set of translation units of our project we would have windows implementation.